# Proper css combinators for rotating a 3-D cube

Tags: css

I want to rotate the cube as one hovers over the red div. I am unable to find the css combinator to achieve this. I think to rotate `#cube`, i need to use adjacent sibling selector (+) but it is not working.

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 perspective: 1000px;
 perspective-origin: 100px 100px;
}
#cube {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 2s;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cube div {
 border: 2px solid black;
 position: absolute; 
 border-radius: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
#front {
 transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(0,34,62,0.3);
}
#right {
 transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
    background-color: rgba(110,34,162,0.3);
}
#back {
 transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(20,4,62,0.3);
}
#left {
 transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(80,134,2,0.3);
}
#top {
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
 background-color: rgba(80,234,200,0.3);
}
#bottom {
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
 background-color: rgba(180,234,2,0.3);
}
#horizontal {
 position: absolute;
 top: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
#horizontal:hover + #cube{
 transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
    <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div id="cube">
          <div id="front"><h1>1</h1></div>
          <div id="right"><h1>2</h1></div>
          <div id="back"><h1>3</h1></div>
          <div id="left"><h1>4</h1></div>
          <div id="top"><h1>5</h1></div>
          <div id="bottom"><h1>6</h1></div>
      </div>
   <div id="horizontal"></div>
   <div id="vertical"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not possible in CSS3. Can I do it with JQuery? It's possible with that

Comment: Oh!.......can u give me any alternative in CSS......and also tell me isnt #cube a sibling of #horizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thery are siblings, but CSS rules only go *forward*. Just change horizontal position in the DOM and it will work

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 perspective: 1000px;
 perspective-origin: 100px 100px;
}
#cube {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 2s;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cube div {
 border: 2px solid black;
 position: absolute; 
 border-radius: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
#front {
 transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(0,34,62,0.3);
}
#right {
 transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
    background-color: rgba(110,34,162,0.3);
}
#back {
 transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(20,4,62,0.3);
}
#left {
 transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
 background-color: rgba(80,134,2,0.3);
}
#top {
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
 background-color: rgba(80,234,200,0.3);
}
#bottom {
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
 background-color: rgba(180,234,2,0.3);
}
#horizontal {
 position: absolute;
 top: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
#horizontal:hover + #cube{
 transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
    <body>
     <div id="container">
   <div id="horizontal"></div>
      <div id="cube">
          <div id="front"><h1>1</h1></div>
          <div id="right"><h1>2</h1></div>
          <div id="back"><h1>3</h1></div>
          <div id="left"><h1>4</h1></div>
          <div id="top"><h1>5</h1></div>
          <div id="bottom"><h1>6</h1></div>
      </div>
   <div id="vertical"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```